Closed form solution for Cosine Double integral $\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy \frac{1}{\alpha+\beta(\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(x-y))}$
Hello Wizards of Stack,
I was wondering if anyone knew of a closed form solution for the following double integral(s) in terms of known elementary or even special functions. Here are the Integrals
$$I(z)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy \frac{1}{\alpha(z)+\beta(z)(\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(x-y))}$$
and
$$J(z)=\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy \frac{\cos(x)}{\alpha(z)+\beta(z)(\cos(x)+\cos(y)+\cos(x-y))}$$
where
$$\alpha(z)= 2 z+2 z^2 -1\quad \beta(z)= 2 z^2, \quad z\in (-\epsilon,\epsilon)\subset\mathbb{R},\ \epsilon>0$$
where $\epsilon$ can be as small as possible but non zero.
I am interested in computing $$I+J$$, so I will start with $I$ (unless there's a clever way to get to $I+J$ directly.
Edit: Steps I've Done
I've added the steps I've taken to tackle the problem (through Complex Analysis) but the problem is that I get to a double contour integral, something that I've never seen before. To illustrate note that using
$$ \cos(\zeta)= \frac{e^{i\zeta}+e^{-i\zeta}}{2}$$ and using
$$e^{ix}= s \quad e^{iy}=w$$
Let us define
$\Gamma:= \frac{\alpha(z)}{\beta(z)}=\frac{1}{z}+1-\frac{1}{2z^2}$ so that we can ignore the prefactor $\frac{1}{\beta(z)}$
we have
$$I(z)= \int_{|s|=1}\int_{|w|=1} \frac{ds}{is}\ \frac{dw}{iw} \frac{2}{2\Gamma+ s+\frac{1}{s}+w+\frac{1}{w}+\frac{w}{s}+\frac{s}{w}}$$
which is equivalent to
$$I(z)= -\int_{|s|=1}\int_{|w|=1} ds\ dw \frac{2}{2\Gamma sw+ (s+w)(1+sw)+s^2+w^2}$$
Feeding one of the integrals to Mathematica (say $ds$) and using the fact that $\lim_{z\to 0} \Gamma(z)\to -\infty,$ so that we may $\color{red}{\textrm{ choose } \epsilon \textrm{ small enough}}$ to yield
$$-\int_{|w|=1} dw \frac{\color{red}{(-1)}2 i \pi }{\sqrt{\left(w^2+2 \Gamma  w+1\right)^2-4 w (w+1)^2}}$$
But integrating that along the $w$ contour breaks Mathematica. I think it's because of the branch although I feel like I'm close to the solution but caught up with something silly.

Welcome to [math.se] SE. Take a [tour]. You'll find that simple "Here's the statement of my question, solve it for me" posts will be poorly received. What is better is for you to add context (with an [edit]): What you understand about the problem, what you've tried so far, etc.; something both to show you are part of the learning experience and to help us guide you to the appropriate help. You can consult this link for further guidance.

Hello @AnotherUser, thank you for the comment! I've updated my original post and added the steps I've taken!

The integrals over $dy$ are zero because the upper and lower bounds are both $\pi$ :-)

@user170231  Sorry, there were typos. That was supposed to be a cos(x) instead of 1

@R.J.Mathar ah thanks for pointing that out! It was a typo, the bounds are from -$\pi$ to $\pi$

$$
I =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy
\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta[\cos x + \cos y +\cos(x-y)]}
$$
$$
 =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy
\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta[\cos x + \cos y +\cos x\cos y +\sin x \sin y]}
$$
$$
 =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy
\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta[\cos x + (1+\cos x)\cos y +\sin x \sin y]}
$$
$$
 =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy
\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta\cos x + \beta (1+\cos x)\cos y +\beta \sin x \sin y}
$$
$$
 =
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dy
\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta\cos x + \beta\sqrt{2+2\cos x}\cos(\tau- y)}
$$
with $\tan \tau = \frac{\sin x}{1+\cos x}$.
$$
I =
2\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\int_{0}^{\pi}dy
\frac{1}{\alpha+\beta\cos x + \beta\sqrt{2+2\cos x}\cos y}
$$
and this is integral 3.661.4 in the Gradsteyn-Ryzhik tables
$$
=
2\pi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(\alpha+\beta \cos x)^2-\beta^2(2+2\cos x)}}
$$
$$
=
2\pi \int_{-\pi}^{\pi}dx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-2\beta^2 +2\beta(\alpha-\beta)\cos x +\beta^2\cos^2 x}}
$$
this ought to be the same as "unwinding" the circular contour in the
original proposal... (?)
$$
=
4\pi \int_0^{\pi}dx
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-2\beta^2 +2\beta(\alpha-\beta)\cos x +\beta^2\cos^2 x}}
$$
$$
=
-4\pi \int_1^{-1}dt
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-2\beta^2 +2\beta(\alpha-\beta)t+\beta^2 t}[\sin x]}
$$
$$
=
4\pi \int_{-1}^1 dt
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\alpha^2-2\beta^2 +2\beta(\alpha-\beta)t+\beta^2 t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
$$
= 
\frac{4\pi}{\beta} \int_{-1}^1 dt 
\frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}-2 +2(\alpha/\beta-1)t+t^2}\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
The zeros $t_{1,2}$ of the quadratic polynomial in the square root are
$$
\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}-2 +2(\alpha/\beta-1)t+t^2
=(t-t_1)(t-t_2)
$$
with
$$
t_{1,2}
=1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\pm \sqrt{(1-\frac{\alpha}{\beta})^2+2-\frac{\alpha^2}{\beta^2}}
=\frac{1-2z}{2z^2}\pm \sqrt{\frac{(z-1)^2}{z^2}}
$$
$$
=\frac{1-2z}{2z^2}\pm \frac{z-1}{z}.
$$
where the upper sign defines $t_1=(1-2z)/(2z^2)+(z-1)/z=(1-3z+z^2)/z^2$, the lower sign $t_2=(1-2z)/2z^2-(z-1)/z=(1-z-z^2)/z^2$.
[Note: if we argue that $t_{1,2}=\frac{1-2z}{2z^2}\pm |\frac{z-1}{z}|$, the role of $t_1$ and $t_2$ is swapped for $z>0$ and the sign relations that follow may differ...]
So this looks like an elliptic integral
$$
I=
\frac{4\pi}{\beta} \int_{-1}^1 dt
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(t-t_1)(t-t_2)}\sqrt{1-t^2}}
$$
The further detailed treatment depends on whether $t_{1,2}$ are real-valued
and/or inside the region from $-1$ to 1, as discussed in the Byrd - Friedman
book of elliptic integrals. If $z$ is small and negative or small and positive, $t_{1,2}$ are
both large positive, $t_1,t_2>1$.
If $z$ is small and negative, $1<t_2<t_1$; if $z$ is small and positive $1<t_1<t_2$.
$$
I=
\frac{4\pi}{\beta} \int_{-1}^1 dt
\frac{1}{\sqrt{(t_1-t)(t_2-t)}\sqrt{(1+t)(1-t)}}
$$
is an elliptic integral $F$ of the first kind, see 252.00 in the Byrd-Friedman book and 3.147.2 in the Gradsteyn-Ryzhik tables.
To quote this formula:
$$
\int_d^y \frac{dt}{\sqrt{(a-t)(b-t)(c-t)(t-d)}} = gF(\varphi,k)
$$
where
$$
a>b>c\ge y>d,\quad d=-1,c=y=1
$$
$t_1$ and $t_2$ are $a$ and $b$ or vice versa, depending on the sign of $\epsilon$.
$$
k^2\equiv \frac{(a-b)(c-d)}{(a-c)(b-d)};
$$
$$
g\equiv \frac{2}{\sqrt{(a-c)(b-d)}};
$$
$$
\sin\varphi \equiv \sqrt{\frac{(a-c)(y-d)}{(c-d)(a-y)}}.
$$
In our case $\varphi=90^\circ$ and the integral is a complete elliptic integral of the first kind.

Thank you for the great answer and for referencing the integral books, that was awesome! One small comment, I think you'd need $$t_{1,2}=\frac{1-2z}{2z^2}\pm \left|\frac{z-1}{z}\right|$$ due to the sign inside. I also looked at the reference for the integral $J$ and following your same steps $$J\sim \int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{t}{\sqrt{(a-t)(b-t)(1-t)(t-(-1))}}$$ , but the Bryd-Friedman book (252.11) with $m=1$ gives this result as $$\int_{-1}^{+1} \frac{t}{\sqrt{(a-t)(b-t)(1-t)(t-(-1))}}=(-1)^{m=1}g \int_{0}^{u_1} \frac{(1-\alpha_1^2 {\rm sn}^2(u))^{m=1}}{(1-\alpha^2 {\rm sn}^2(u))^{m=1}}du$$-

where $$\alpha_1= \frac{a ((-1)-1)}{(-1)(a-1)}= \frac{2 a}{a-1}$$ and $$u_1= {\rm sn}^{-1}(\sin(\varphi))$$ and $$\alpha^2= \frac{(-1)-(1)}{a-(1)}=2\frac{1}{1-a}$$ and ${\rm sn}(u)$ is the Jacobi Elliptical "ess-sine" function My question is, do you know how to simplify it further?

I know that we could write add and subtract $\alpha^2 {\rm sn}^2(u)$ to find $$J=\frac{4\pi}{\beta} (-1) g \left(\underbrace{\int_{0}^{u_1}du}{=  F(\varphi,k)}+ (\alpha^2-\alpha_1^2) \int{0}^{u_{1}} \frac{{\rm sn}^2(u)}{1- \alpha^2 {\rm sn^2(u)}}du\right)$$ but do you have any information on the second integral? Many thanks!

For the $J$-integral and Byrd-Friemann's right hand side of 252.11 at m=1 one wants to evaluate the $V_{0,1}$ integrals in 340.04 of the Byrd-Friedmann book, which are a complete elliptic integral of the first and third kind, as defined in 336.00 and 336.01. C++ implementations of these, based on the GNU scientific library, are in the ancillary files ByrdEllip.cxx (headers ByrdEllip.h ) in my https://arxiv.org/abs/2203.17227 .

Thank you! There's so much stuff about Elliptical Integrals I need to learn :)
